# One dimensional Klein-Gordon harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, klein-gordon-equation

## Some context:

Let us consider a spinless charged massive particle of mass $m$, charge $q$ in an electrostatic potential $V(x) = \frac{m}{2q}\omega^2x^2$.

The corresponding **stationary Klein-Gordon equation** is then:

$$
\left(-\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + m^2\right)\phi(x) = (E-qV(x))^2\phi(x)
$$

One may right it in the following form:

$$
\frac{(E^2-m^2)}{2m} \phi(x) = \left(\frac{p_x^2}{2m} + W(x)\right)\phi(x) = H\phi(x)
$$

where $W(x) = \frac{E}{2}\omega^2x^2 - \frac{1}{8}m\omega^4 x^4$

Then, we may want to evaluate the $E_n$ levels of energy. To do so, I had to consider the pertubative angle: write $H = H_0 + V_p$ where:

- $H_0 = \frac{p_x^2}{2m} + \frac{E}{2}\omega^2x^2 = \frac{p_x^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\tilde\omega^2x^2$, $\quad \tilde \omega^2 = \frac{E}{m}\omega^2$
- The perturbation $V_p = - \frac{1}{8}m\omega^4 x^4$.

Finally, the energy levels $E_n$ satisfy, considering first order correction:

$$
\dfrac{E^2_n - m^2}{2m} = \tilde\omega(n+1/2)+ \langle n|V_p|n \rangle = \tilde\omega(n+1/2) - \frac{1}{8}m^2\omega^4 \langle n|X^4|n \rangle
$$

Using the fact that $\langle n|X^4|n \rangle = \frac{3}{4m^2\tilde\omega^2} (2n^2+2n+1)$ :

$$
\dfrac{E^2_n - m^2}{2m} = \sqrt{\frac{E_n}{m}}\omega(n+1/2) - \frac{3 m}{32 E_n^2}\omega^2 (2n^2+2n+1)\quad (\star)
$$

## The question:

- Is $(\star)$ correct?
- If so, solve $(\star)$ for in the non-relativistic limit

I find it really difficult to solve it in the non-relativistic limit since we have $E_n$ at different powers... So it makes me wonder whether I made a mistake in $(\star)$ or whether I really know how to take the non-relativistic limit properly (I tried without being alble to find any solvable equation in $E_n$ taking the first order for $m\to \infty$).